# concat css from dependencies

Tags: gulp, browserify

I use browserify for dependency injection of my angular modules. However, this is only for javascript and some of my angular modules in my node_modules/ also include css. What's the best way to concatenate these files into a single css file. I think this should be easy but can't find any project that does exactly what I do in a proper manner. I'm sure there must be more people using browserify that came across the same problem.

Comment: have a look at [gulp-patterns](https://github.com/johnpapa/gulp-patterns), it uses `wiredep`, `inject`, `csso` in the process